# Visual Studio C++ transparent form

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

I have a form with a BMP image (picture box) on top of it. The part of the bmp that is partially transparent but isn't 100% see through shows the form in the background instead of my desktop or other windows.

I've been trying to hide the form completely and have the desktop show through, but haven't found any way to do that yet...

Can anyone help

Comment: Could you provide the code you're currently using?

Comment: yes. Where can I send the code?

Comment: Simply edit your question and add the relevant lines of codes.

Comment: I created standart MFC Visual Studio C++ project and only added one picture on the form.(The part of the image is partially transparent)

Comment: Making the window transparent requires setting the form's TransparencyKey property.  Set the form's BackColor property to match.  Color.Fuchsia is a good fuchsed up color that isn't likely to appear in the bitmap.  If the main window isn't a Form then you'll need to tinker with WS_EX_LAYEREDWINDOW and SetLayeredWindowAttributes() to select the color key.